# How to implement a stream that can be splitted by newline

Tags: c++, c, newline, zlib, unzip

The following code works, but is about twice as inefficient compared to when I use a (linux) pipe that gives unzipped data to the (modified) program. I need a steady stream within the program which I can keep splitting by `\n`. Is there a way to do this using a (string?) stream or any other trick?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
static const int unzipBufferSize = 8192;
long long int counter = 0;
int i = 0, p = 0, n = 0;
int offset = 0;
char *end = NULL;
char *begin = NULL;
unsigned char unzipBuffer[unzipBufferSize];
unsigned int unzippedBytes;
char * inFileName = argv[1];
char buffer[200];
buffer[0] = '\0';
bool breaker = false;
char pch[4][200];
Read *aRead = new Read;
gzFile inFileZ;
inFileZ = gzopen(inFileName, "rb");
while (true) {
    unzippedBytes = gzread(inFileZ, unzipBuffer, unzipBufferSize);
    if (unzippedBytes > 0) {
        unzipBuffer[unzippedBytes] = '\0'; //put a 0-char after the total buffer
        begin = (char*) &unzipBuffer[0]; // point to the address of the first char
        do {
            end = strchr(begin,(int)'\n'); //find the end of line
            if (end != NULL) *(end) = '\0'; // put 0-char to use it as a c-string
            pch[p][0] = '\0'; \\ put a 0-char to be able to strcat
            if (strlen(buffer) > 0) { // if buffer from previous iteration contains something
                strcat(pch[p], buffer); // cat it to the p-th pch
                buffer[0] = '\0'; \\ set buffer to null-string or ""
            }
            strcat(pch[p], begin); // put begin (or rest of line in case there was a buffer into p-th pch

            if (end != NULL) { // see if it already points to something
                begin = end+1; // if so, advance begin to old end+1
                p++;
            }

            if(p>3) { // a 'read' contains 4 lines, so if p>3
                strcat(aRead->bases,pch[1]); // we use line 2 and 4 as
                strcat(aRead->scores,pch[3]); // bases and scores
                //do things with the reads
                aRead->bases[0] = '\0'; //put them back to 0-char
                aRead->scores[0] = '\0';
                p = 0; // start counting next 4 lines
            }

        } 
        while (end != NULL );
        strcat(buffer,pch[p]); //move the left-over of unzipBuffer to buffer
    }
    else {
        break; // when no unzippedBytes, exit the loop
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use e.g. [the Boost iostreams library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) which have classes for gzipped files. Then you can use the normal `std::getline` to read on a line by line basis.

Comment: The purpose of this program is to be as fast as possible. Am I wrong in assuming that using a C++ library like Boost would not be as fast as when we keep this in C, using c-strings?

Comment: Also I am very much wondering how this can be done the most simple way, without using external libraries. One purpose of zlib should be to directly use the data that gets extracted, right? Without the need of using other libraries...

Comment: Most big standard library implementations are pretty well optimized, and so is the Boost library. The thing is that you need to *measure* before you can say anything.

Comment: Using C strings _well_ might be faster. Using C strings the way you're using them (ie, badly) is not the path to great performance. Either carefully track lengths and minimize copies, or use a well-written library. Calling `strcat` all over the place is the worst of both worlds.

Comment: @Niels: You don't want to directly use the data that gets extracted: you want to do formatted reading from a stream. That's the whole purpose of the `iostream` library. If there weren't existing libraries that already set this up for you, I would have suggested that you learn how to do it yourself and write your own subclass of `std::streambuf` that wraps `zlib`.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is probably the standard C string library.

With using `strxxx()` funcions, you are iterating through the complete buffer *multiple times* each call, first for `strchr()`, then for `strlen()`, then for each of the `strcat()` calls.
Using the standard library is a nice thing, but here, it's just plain inefficient.

Try if you could come up with something simpler that touches each character only once like (code just to show the principle, do not expect it working):

```
do
{
    do
    {
       *tp++ = *sp++;
    } while (sp < buffer_end && *sp != '\n');

    /* new line, do whatever it requires */
    ...
    /* reset tp to beginning of buffer */
} while (sp < buffer_end);
```

Comment: The four lines of a 'read' come together. Isn't this too simplistic then?

Comment: And at which point should I get a new unzipBuffer from gzread here? What should I imagine tp and sp to be?

Comment: I just wanted to show you the principle (touch each array element only once) instead of doing your work ;)

Comment: Alright, well thanks anyway of course... I will need a little bit of more help of someone. The idea of all the str*** functions making a lot of extra iterations is clear. I want to get rid of that. Just don't know howto renew the stream (unzipBuffer) and then also knowing what to do with it every time...

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to get this to work, but all it does is giving a Segmentation Fault at runtime:

```
do {
    unzippedBytes = gzread(inFileZ, unzipBuffer, unzipBufferSize);
    if (unzippedBytes > 0) {

        while (*unzipBuffer < unzippedBytes) {
            *pch = *unzipBuffer++;
            cout << pch;

            i++;
        }
        i=0;
    }
    else break;
} while (true);
```

What am I doing wrong here?